# How do I prevent the TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int' when using keras EarlyStopping?

Tags: python, keras

Here is my code:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=33, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
for u in range(3): #how to efficiently add more layers
    model.add(Dense(33, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(122, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=20, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4)])
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

It doesn't produce that error when I don't use `EarlyStopping`.

Anyone have a fix?

Comment: is this linked to the other question? I thought you had NaN errors without the callback

Comment: Yes @Nick, @Nassim is correct.. this is linked to the other question. `EarlyStopping` compares the subsequent loss/val_loss and if in any of the epoch it becomes `nan` it fails to compare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent loss: nan while if fitting my keras model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472447/how-do-i-prevent-loss-nan-while-if-fitting-my-keras-model)

Comment: I didn't think this problem was related to the nan problem. I'll have to find out if the problem is solved now after I got the answer to the nan question...

Comment: It didn't work. It appears that this is not a duplicate. I still need an answer to this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think about it : you ask to monitor a validation loss without using a validation during the training.

Use

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=20, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4)])
```

For example if you want to have a validation. It will use 20% of your data as validation set. You won't be training on those samples, just validating your model at the end of each epoch.

And as mentionned in your other question about this code : change the last activation to a softmax to use with `categorical_crossentropy`. Or switch the objective to `binary_crossentropy` depending on your needs.