# How do I prevent loss: nan while I'm fitting my keras model?

Tags: python, keras

Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=33, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
for u in range(3): #how to efficiently add more layers
    model.add(Dense(33, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(122, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#This line of code is an update to the question and may be responsible
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=35, batch_size=20, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)])
```

It was running the Epochs and getting better in accuracy but then the loss started being nan and the accuracy went way down. I used `model.predict` and got an error from that as well.

Anyone got a fix?

Comment: How much data do you use? What's the format? What are you trying to preduct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `categorical_crossentropy` as loss function then the last layer of the model should be `softmax`.

Here you are using `sigmoid` which has the chance of making all dimensions of output close to 0 which will result in loss to overflow and hence `nan`.

Comment: Also you should normalize the input and ensure the output is 1-hot coded